# Redshift error - [42703][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: record "list" has no field "table_name";

Tags: stored-procedures, amazon-redshift, recordset, dynamicquery

[42703][500310] Amazon Invalid operation: record "list" has no field "table_name";

I got the above error while executing stored procedure in redshift. The stored procedure as below

My table structure
admin.table_primary_keys
(
table_name varchar(200),
primary_key varchar(500)
)

Stored procedure -

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE admin.sp_load_duplicate_data()
language plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
list RECORD;
keys varchar(2000);
Table_name varchar(2000);
query varchar(2000);

BEGIN
FOR list IN
SELECT table_name,primary_key FROM admin.table_primary_keys
LOOP
select list.primary_key into keys;
select list.table_name into Table_name;
query:='select '''||Table_name||''',count(1) from (select '||keys||', count(1) from '||Table_name||' group by '||keys|| ' having count(1) >1)';

--EXECUTE 'insert into audit.duplicate_table_list(table_name,count) ' || query;
EXECUTE query;
END LOOP;
```

END;
$$;

call admin.sp_load_duplicate_data();

Error - [42703][500310] Amazon Invalid operation: record "list" has no field "table_name";

Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

i figured out the answer for this above issue. i just renamed the table columns as tablename,primarykey ( instead of table_name,primary_key). i think error is due to keywords/reserved word,etc

Thanks